# NodeJS Grab "live" output from other progress

Tags: node.js

(for TL;DR / short question - look below)

I have written a little program in C that spits out a bunch of numbers based on my microphone input (avarage heard sound frequency) - i want to do stuff with those numbers (recognizing whistle patterns etc.). Now the program works fine - it spits out about 30 numbers per second ended with a newline.

Now I need this information in my nodejs program and i actually need to parse it real-time (or as fast as possible).

I've tried using exec and spawn, both with .pipe and just hooking into the .stdout events.

Problem is that those seem to be buffered. Code:

```
whistleListen = spawn('./dist/sndpeek', ['--nodisplay','--print','--rolloff-only']);
whistleListen.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});
```

The effect is that the program starts, then it takes a few seconds, and then instantly i get about 200 lines. It looks like the output is being buffered.

I do not want that - best thing would be to receive it realtime, just keep reading until i hit a \n, then parse the number, and do something with it.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

TL;DR

NodeJS spawns a program (tried exec and spawn), and i hook into the stdout of the program. The program spits a lot of lines with numbers (about 40 lines per second). I need to parse this data realtime, but when i use the callback handles, i get 1 dump of about 200 lines every few seconds. I need to speed it up.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why go through stdout in the first place? why not sockets, pipes?

Comment: I've tried .pipe as well but that seems to be buffered also. Is there another method to just grab the output from the program?

Comment: I don't have that much experience with nodeJS or sockets, could you point me in a direction on where to look?

Comment: google does best, here are 2 links [C sockets](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm) | [node sockets](http://www.hacksparrow.com/tcp-socket-programming-in-node-js.html)

Comment: Aah right, i thought you ment other sockets (filebased sockets) - i know about the TCP sockets and buffers, but i have _very_ little experience in C, so adding this into the program would be very hard for me to accomplish. I know that i can usually just pipe data into other programs - ./program | otherone - and that goes realtime. It must be possible for nodejs to do that with child threads, right?

Comment: Ahaaaa... I'm going to check out socket files :) mkfifo throughput; ./program > throughput and then read it out in node.js

Comment: Hmmm, that doesn't really work.. :/

Comment: Thanks for your help @Amit, but the issue wasn't in NodeJS. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! Turns out it wasn't NodeJS, but my C program. I've added this line

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

and now the fprintf(); doesn't buffer anymore and i get a new line for every .stdout event in my node app.