# How I get result from child_process.execFile live?

Tags: node.js, child-process

I want to get data from C based binary real time, by running Node.js. I know that Node.js can run executable binary file using child_process module.

So I create simple C/Node.js application as below:

```c
// It will be compiled to a.out and run by below Node.js code
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i=0;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var cmd = spawn('./a.out');

cmd.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('stdout : ' + data);
});

cmd.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('stderr : ' + data);
});

cmd.stdout.on('end', function(data) {
    console.log('end');
});
```

And what I expected:

```
00:00] 0
00:01] 1
00:02] 2
...
00:09] 9
00:10] 10
```

But I see:

```
00:10] 0
1
2
...
9
10
```

It looks like all stdout from binary will store to buffer, and after binary is terminated, all buffer data will be displayed.
I expect that cmd.stdout.on('data', callback) will run 10 time, but it run just 1 time.

But I want to get result like stream.
How I can get data like stream, or how I can data by line at real time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By default, stdout in general is buffered until a newline is written. However, if stdout is not a tty (which is the case here with `child_process.spawn()`), all output is buffered, regardless of newlines. You can disable stdout buffering entirely by doing `setbuf(stdout, NULL)` .

I tried the following, it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    setbuf(stdout, NULL);

    int i=0;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Ref : [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281500/nodejs-always-cannt-capture-child-processs-stdout-data-completely-unless-chil) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770295/nodejs-grab-live-output-from-other-progress)